# Can I mod rewrite to a different document root?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, git

Given a URL:

```
http://example.com/some-file.zip
```

The document root for `example.com` is `/var/www/example.com/`

I want apache to:

1. If `/var/www/example.com/some-file.zip` exists, serve it.
2. If `/var/www/example.com/some-file.zip` doesn't exist, check `/var/www/shared/some-file.zip`
3. If `/var/www/shared/some-file.zip` doesn't exist, send a 404

Is this possible?

I've looked in to the Alias directive, but I think this will require me to have something in the URI indicating where the resource is.

Comment: This would be pretty trivial with nginx's `try_files`. Ever considered switching?

Comment: Thanks Michael, you just convinced me to switch. Do you have any links regarding the triviality of a setup like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For files outside the `DocumentRoot`, check out the aptly named documentation section on "[Files Outside the DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/urlmapping.html#outside)" -- you're looking at creating an `Alias`, and you may be able to do it without a redirect.

Comment: I think this is on the right track.. but it will require me to have some indicator of the resource in the URI.. e.g. I can't just alias "/"

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}$1 !-f
RewriteRule (.*) /var/www/shared$1 [last]
```

Comment: core:error "The given path was above the root path"

Comment: This directive is to be used in a _server_ or _virtualhost_ context, not `.htaccess` (or other _directory_ context). However, you'll still need to grant access to `/var/www/shared` in the server config, if not already. @tim

Comment: this works only for apache